# Publishing to npmjs - using a machine user?

Tags: node.js, npm, publish, organization, npmjs

We're currently working on an open source project (wicked.haufe.io, an API Management system), and for this system, we would like to publish an SDK to npmjs.com for situations where you would want to extend the functionality of the system (it's designed for that).

Now, obviously I don't want to publish to npmjs.com using my own user, but would want to use an organization in some way. My questions regarding this (and I didn't find anything appropriate in the npm documentation on this) are:

- Can and should I use a machine user for npmjs.com when publishing? Is this allowed? We'd build and publish from our own build pipelines, and those only use machine credentials, not personal ones.
- Do I need a paid plan even if my organization only wants to publish open source packages?

The second bullet point is not that big an issue, we can do with the minimal $14 for an organization; the first issue is what's interesting.

Best regards, Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding machine credentials have nothing to do with it. The only credentials that matter are when you try to "npm publish", it will ask for npmjs.com credentials which you have already created (and can be anything). As far as company and publishing information for the package, you can arbitrarily include whatever you want in the package.json file. Just type "npm init".

[See link here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json)

I don't think a paid account would be required.

Comment: Thanks, yes, it seems to be okay to just use a shared account for publishing.